# Play Fade-In-Out animation with another animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Starting off, The goal is to have a span element fade in, show a comment indicator, then fade out, after that change the comment indicator (content), and start back from the beginning. Is there anyway to do this in CSS or JS? Currently, it's very upfront with no ease and just switches content.

Here is the steps:

1. Fade In
2. Show Comment Indicator (Content)
3. Fade Out
4. Change Comment Indicator (Content)
5. Fade In (Start back at 1)
6. ETC.

HTML:

```html
    <h1 id="about-header"><span id="comment-indicator-start">//</span> About Me <span id="comment-indicator-end"></span></h1>
```

CSS:

```css
#about-header #comment-indicator-start, #comment-indicator-end {
    display: none;
}

#about-header::before {
    content: "//";
    animation: fadey 1.6s linear forwards, comments-start 8s;
}

@keyframes fadey {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

#about-header::after {
    content: " ";
    animation: comments-end 8s;    
}

@keyframes comments-start {
    0% {
        content: "//"; 
    }
    20% {
        content: "#"; 
    }
    40% {
        content: "<!--";
    }
    60% {
        content: "/*";
    }
    80% {
        content: "'"
    }
    100% {
        content: "--";
    }
}

@keyframes comments-end {
    0% {
        content: ""; 
    }
    20% {
        content: ""; 
    }
    40% {
        content: "-->";
    }
    60% {
        content: "*/";
    }
    80% {
        content: ""
    }
    100% {
        content: "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

###### Background

I found the closest solution that has most of what I asked for. Including the fading in and out with changing content in CSS.

###### Issue/Needed Improvement

With the code below, yes it achieves most things asked, but is jagged and not as smooth as possible. When the content changes it's sharp and can sometimes make the animation not look good.

###### Code

HTML:

```html
<h1 id="about-header"><span id="comment-indicator-start">//</span> About Me <span id="comment-indicator-end"></span></h1>
```

CSS:

```css
#about-header #comment-indicator-start, #comment-indicator-end {
    display: none;
}

#about-header::before {
    content: "//";
    animation: comments-start 8s, fadeInOut 1.56s linear -1s 6;
}

#about-header::after {
    content: " ";
    animation: comments-end 8s, fadeInOut 1.56s linear -1s 6;  
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    } 50% {
      opacity: 1;
    } 100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

@keyframes comments-start {
    0% {
        content: "//"; 
    }
    20% {
        content: "#"; 
    }
    40% {
        content: "<!--";
    }
    60% {
        content: "/*";
    }
    80% {
        content: "'"
    }
    100% {
        content: "--";
    }
}

@keyframes comments-end {
    0% {
        content: "";
    }
    20% {
        content: ""; 
    }
    40% {
        content: "-->"; 
    }
    60% {
        content: "*/";
    }
    80% {
        content: ""
    }
    100% {
        content: "";
    }
}
```